# JSTL in Spring 3.1.1

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm going a bit mad . . . Where is the JSTL library in the Spring 3.1.1 release?

Thanks Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nowhere. You must download it and install it separately. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Thanks . . . I went ahead and did that.  JSTL has been in past releases, I believe.